# First and last citations of .bib file not showing in compiled references in LaTeX file

Tags: bibliographies, citing, overleaf

I have written a .bib file that includes 36 references. The filename is

> bibliography.bib

I added this at the bottom of my LaTeX document:

```
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

However, the first and last elements of the .bib file do not get shown. Meaning only 34/36 total references are shown in the compiled file. I am working with Overleaf.

This is what *bibliography.bib* looks like (references b1 and b36 do not show up in the compiled LaTeX document):

```
@article{b1,
author = {J. Aboobaker and E. Ilavarasan},
title = {A Survey on Sarcasm detection and challenges},
year = {2020},
pages = {pp. 1234-1240},
doi = {10.1109/ICACCS48705.2020.9074163},
}

@article{b2,
author = {Filik, R. Turcan A, Ralph-Nearman C, Pitiot A},
title = {What is the difference between irony and sarcasm? An fMRI study},
year = {2019},
month = {Jun},
pages = {112-122},
doi = {10.1016/j.cortex.2019.01.025},
unidentified = {Cortex. ;115:. EpubFeb 7. PMID: 30807881},
}

@article{b3,
author = {Gibbs, R. W.},
title = {On the psycholinguistics of sarcasm},
journal = {Journal of Experimental Psychology: General},
year = {1986},
volume = {115},
number = {1},
pages = {3-15},
url = {https://doi.org/10.1037/0096-3445.115.1.3},
}

.
.
.

@article{b34,
author = {Abdul-Mageed, Muhammad and Diab, Mona and Kubler, Sandra},
title = {SAMAR: Subjectivity and sentiment analysis for Arabic social media},
journal = {Computer Speech & Language},
year = {2014},
volume = {10},
number = {1016},
pages = {20-37},
doi = {28.. /j.csl.2013.03.001},
}

@misc{b35,
author = {Moha Taher},
note = {\url{https://github.com/mohataher/arabic-stop-words}},
}

@misc{b36,
author = {Sebastian Ruder},
title = {Why You Should Do NLP Beyond English},
year = {2020},
note = {\url{https://ruder.io/nlp-beyond-english/}},
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you `\cite` the relevant entries or issue a `\nocite{*}` to add all entries from the `.bib` file to the bibliography? Normally BibTeX will only add entries to the bibliography that were actually `\cite`d. With `\nocite{*}` you add all entries regardless of whether they were cited or not.

Comment: That is exactly what it is, thank you. I thought it had something to do with formatting.

Comment: This may not the the source of your problem, but it is an error that must be fixed: The ampersand must be escaped to `\&` in TeX otherwise you get an error. `journal = {Computer Speech & Language},` should be `journal = {Computer Speech \& Language},`.

Comment: Thank you for noting that, I will fix that and any other characters that need escaping.